# Unity3D Warning Updating from Ubuntu 12 to 14

Tags: 12.04, unity, 14.04, nvidia, upgrade

When I try to update from Ubuntu 12 to 14 I get the following warning:

`Running the 'unity' desktop environment is not fully supported by your graphics hardware. You will maybe end up in a very slow environment after the upgrade. Our advice is to keep the LTS version for now. For more information see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/UpdateManagerWarningForUnity3D Do you still want to continue with the upgrade?`

When I follow the link for the error explanation it says: `your machine does not have 3D support for running the unity desktop environment.` I have an NVIDIA graphics card am using the proprietary driver (331-updates). What does this specific part of the error message mean, does this indicate there is a  problem with my current driver setup, and should I upgrade Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your graphics card does not have sufficient 3D capabilities to run the Unity3D interface fluently.

Is it an old card?
You might want to use a different desktop environment once you finished updating. Like XFCE or LXDE.

Comment: Not old: `lspci | grep VGA` yields:
`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GTX 650] (rev a1)`

Comment: Must be a mistake then. That card should be more than enough to run Unity3D.

Comment: Does that mean Ubuntu is mistaken or you were mistaken? The card seems to be working properly, is there a way to test whether it is using Unity3D correctly currently?