# How to check and set Refresh Rate with Nvidia Graphics Card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, graphics, xorg

When I tried to update from Ubuntu 12 to Ubuntu 14 I got a [warning message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523303/unity3d-warning-updating-from-ubuntu-12-to-14) against updating stating that `your machine does not have 3D support for running the unity desktop environment.` My graphics card is a relatively new NVIDIA card, so this should not be a problem:

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GTX 650] (rev a1)
```

In trying to troubleshoot whether or not I have a problem (either currently or if I update), I tried looking at the solutions to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/155351/242873) on refresh rates (eyes also hurting from staring at the screen) and got an error message.

```
xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1600 x 900, maximum 1600 x 900
default connected 1600x900+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1600x900        0.0* 
   1024x768        0.0  
   800x600         0.0  
   640x480         0.0
```

If I try to set the refresh rate I get an error message:

```
xrandr -r 75
Rate 75.0 Hz not available for this size
```

I get this same error message for any value. I also tried using `compiz` to set the refresh rate based on this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/147584). However, this does not seem to do anything (both extremely low and extremely high values do not perceptibly change the screen). When I try to go into the driving setting in the menu item `NVIDIA X Server Settings` for the proprietary driver, I do not see any options at all, let alone options for things like refresh rate. I am using the proprietary NVIDIA driver (331-updates). Also if it is relevant I previously had an [issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/141606/242873) where at startup the GUI would not boot and it would say “The system is running in low-graphics mode”. [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/296217/242873) fixing a broken xorg file fixed that problem. If relevant, my xorg file now looks like this:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
        Driver          "vesa"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

In short, I'd like to know whether my graphics driver is having issues, if so how to fix it, and how to change my refresh rate.